# How to Return Pandas Group By Statements as a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to group a Pandas dataframe by a few columns and then prepare some summary statistics for other columns. I am used to R's Dplyr group_by() and summarise() interfaces and I am struggling to do the equivalent with Panda's. The following reproducible code-snippet **almost** produces the expected results:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id':[1,2,1,3,3,],
    'score':[1,1,2,2,2],
    'tag': [1,2,2,1,2]
})

grouped_df = df.groupby(['user_id', 'tag']).agg(
    example = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'score', aggfunc = sum))

grouped_df['user_id']
```

The issue is that the grouping does not produce a "normal" Pandas df. My last statement throws an error because I cannot access the dataframe by column names. Looking at a head statement I can see it is in a different format where a single value can encompass multiple cells of the output in the group_by statement. The expected output is that I can reference grouped_df['user_id'] and work with it and create columns like any other Pandas df. What changes need to be made here?

Comment: `grouped_df=df.groupby(['user_id', 'tag']).agg(
    example = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'score', aggfunc = sum)).reset_index()` , you have to reset the index

Comment: `df.groupby(..., as_index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you did `groupby`, `user_id` became part of the index.

You can recover it in the columns with

```
grouped_df = grouped_df.reset_index()
grouped_df['user_id']
```

Comment: That works thank you. Interestingly enough I tried setting as_index=False and it threw an error for some reason, maybe related to grouping by multiple terms?